# Projection of an arbitrary triangle onto an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry

I have spent about ten hours on the following problem and I guess it is time to ask for help!

It is known that for any given triangle T in space there is a plane such that the projection of T onto this plane is an equilateral triangle. I want to find the normal vector of this plane given the coordinates of the vertices of T, or vectors that form T (sides of T as vectors), or vectors formed by connecting the origin to vertices, or...............
I want an explicit and nice solution. I can come up with an ugly expression but I want something elegant. (I haven't seen this in a book but intuitively one is inclined toward the assumption that an elegant solution must exist, perhaps by representing T in a novel and non-standard way).
Many Thanks in advance,
Ali

Comment: Related: ["Can one always map a given triangle into a triangle with chosen angles by means of a parallel projection?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1088066/409) and ["Prove that every triangle is the orthogonal projection of an equilateral one"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1571863/409).