# generalization oh lhuillier´s thorem

Tags: geometry, projection

lhuillier´s thorem states thatEvery triangle can be considered
as the normal projection of a triangle of given form (an equilateral triangle, for indtance). see the discussion here : [Projection of an arbitrary triangle onto an equilateral triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594994/projection-of-an-arbitrary-triangle-onto-an-equilateral-triangle)

my qestion is under which conditions  a general n-polygon can be orthogonally projected on a regular n-polygon?